# What should we do to run NSoperationqueue after app enters applicationDidEnterBackground?

Tags: ios, ios7

I want to download even when app enters in bacground after quiting home button.But Will NSoperationqueue do it automatically ?
should I set UI Background Modes in Plist with value "Fetch" ?

If it is possible to run NSoperationqueue in app background mode, Will UIupdation happen only after entering foreground only?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSURLSession` to download in background (iOS7+ only).

Tutorial: [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial)

NSURLSession WWDC 2013 Video: [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/#705)

Hope this helps.

==========UPDATE===========

It seems you want to perform background fetch.

NSOperationQueue won't do it automatically. You'll need to enable background fetch in capabilities tab of your app's target.

[image]

After that specify `Required background modes` in your plist.

[image]

**Is it possible to run NSoperationqueue in app background mode ?**

Yes it is. You can use NSOperationQueue in background fetch handler of AppDelegate

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

PS. A good [read](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/) on using background fetch.

Comment: Hi @JeffWood, Sorry! I was misled with the term "Download" in your question. Anyway, It seems you want to perform background fetch. NSOperationQueue won't do it automatically. You'll need to enable background fetch in capabilities tab of your app's target (refer : https://space.zeo.net/g/1qgnp ). After that specify required background modes in your plist (refer: https://space.zeo.net/g/2wbp6)

Comment: @JeffWood Here is a tutorial which explains using background fetch in good depth : http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/ .

You can use NSOperationQueue in background fetch handler of AppDelegate `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler`